# Getting TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to' in Django Project?

Tags: python, django

I have just started learning Django frame work and got stuck after getting an unexpected error as below:-(I have tried to post all information, which i find necessary to be here)

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'
```

I got this error while running command  `python manage.py makemigrations`
My project contains only one Model class `Products`

**My Model Class:-**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pic = models.DateTimeField(upload_to="myimages")
```

I am added my app in INSTALLED_APPS fields in setting.py

[image: My Project My Structure.]

**Full Error Track:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\products\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Products(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\products\models.py", line 9, in Products
    pic = models.DateTimeField(upload_to="myimages")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1158, in __init__
    super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'

C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject>cls

C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\products\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Products(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\products\models.py", line 9, in Products
    pic = models.DateTimeField(upload_to="myimages")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1158, in __init__
    super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'
```

Thanks in advance.
Hope to here from you soon.

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: @It_is_Chris ok i am adding.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have added full Error track please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like `DateTimeField` accepts the `upload_to` keyword argument.

`pic = models.DateTimeField(upload_to="myimages")`

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield).

Were you trying to use another Model Field? e.g., `ImageField`, `FileField`

Comment: I have nothing to say more then sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of it. Try with proper field

```
pic = models.DateTimeField(upload_to="myimages")
```